GStreamer plugins-bad not being installed properly in a docker container
I'm trying to install GStreamer in a Docker container using the following command:
apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev \
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad \
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-tools \
gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 \
gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio

Reference: GStreamer Installation on Linux
However, after installation, when I run gst-inspect-1.0 | grep nv, I don't see any of the NVIDIA plugins that should be installed from plugins-bad. Here are the results:
audioconvert:  audioconvert: Audio converter
audiofx:  audioinvert: Audio inversion
autoconvert:  autoconvert: Select converter based on caps
autoconvert:  autodeinterlace: Select deinterlacer, and converters based on caps
autoconvert:  autovideoconvert: Select color space converter and scalers based on caps
autoconvert:  autovideoflip: Flip the video plugging the right element depending on caps
bayer:  rgb2bayer: RGB to Bayer converter
closedcaption:  ccconverter: Closed Caption Converter
debugutilsbad:  errorignore: Convert some GstFlowReturn types into others
dsd:  dsdconvert: DSD converter
ivtc:  ivtc: Inverse Telecine
libav:  avdec_dsicinvideo: libav Delphine Software International CIN video decoder
libav:  avdec_idcinvideo: libav id Quake II CIN video decoder
libav:  avdec_twinvq: libav VQF TwinVQ decoder
libav:  avdec_wnv1: libav Winnov WNV1 decoder
opengl:  glcolorconvert: OpenGL color converter
opengl:  gleffects_blur: Blur with 9x9 separable convolution Effect
opengl:  gleffects_laplacian: Laplacian Convolution Demo Effect
opengl:  glviewconvert: OpenGL Multiview/3D conversion filter
rtponvif:  rtponvifparse: ONVIF NTP timestamps RTP extension
rtponvif:  rtponviftimestamp: ONVIF NTP timestamps RTP extension
videoconvertscale:  videoconvert: Video colorspace converter
videoconvertscale:  videoconvertscale: Video colorspace converter and scaler
videoconvertscale:  videoscale: Video scaler
vulkan:  vulkancolorconvert: Vulkan Color Convert
vulkan:  vulkanviewconvert: Vulkan View Convert

None of the NVIDIA plugins are actually installed, even though they should be included in plugins-bad.
I have tried using containers based on both Ubuntu and Debian (arm64) with fresh images, but nothing has worked so far. My plan is to leverage the host GPU with the NVIDIA container toolkit.
So far, nvidia-smi works in the container, so I believe the NVIDIA driver is installed properly. However, I don't know why the GStreamer plugins won't install correctly.
I have tried to use a prebuilt docker image with gstreamer already installed, but that did not give the nvidia plugins either.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Hi, please read formatting help. It will help to understand your question

When it comes to accelerated NVIDIA accelerated GStreamer in Docker, the elemets are actually shared from the host device to the Docker.
We have seen similar issues in the past, and the most common cause we have seen is a missmatch between the OS version of the host Jetson device and the one being used in docker.
Please let us know if you continue having issues.
